# Can Kafka Connect be part of my Hadoop Cluster?

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am currently using one Hadoop cluster of 10 nodes (1 Name Node and 9 Data Nodes) in which Hbase, Hive, Kafka, Zookeeper and other echo systems of Hadoop are running. Now I want to fetch data from RDBMS and store it in HDFS in real time. Can we do that by using Confluent Source Connector and HDFS2 Sink Connector with in the same cluster or do I need to have a separate cluster for Kafka Connect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Kafka Connect is a standalone Java process, just like each of the other components you mentioned.

> do I need to have a separate cluster for Kafka Connect

That would be preferred, but is optional